# i want to find an field in collection and also want to find an object id in array and push more object in sub array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Mongo DB collection is

```
{ 
  findId: xyz,
  mainArray:[{
            andFindThisObjectId:abc,
            pushInThisArray:[{newValue,anotherValue}}
  }]
}
```

so here i want to find and push more value in **pushInThisArray** Field

Comment: `{newValue,anotherValue}` is not valid BSON? please give more details for your question...

Comment: pushInThisArray:[{newValue,anotherValue}} => pushInThisArray:[{newValue,anotherValue}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({
                  $and:[{"findId":"BL0303160"},
                        {"mainArray._id":ObjectId("56d7a674af6cb08406f3bf8a")}
                       ]},
                  {$push:{
                          "mainArray.$.pushInThisArray":
                                      {"myName":"Pratik", 
                                        "myPc":"HP"}
                  }});
```